# What type of component should be used to write SDK to support on windows 8.1 and windows universal devices

Tags: windows, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1, win-universal-app, windows-8.1-universal

I have a requirement to develop a SDK(kind of class library) for Windows app supporting Windows 8.1 and Windows universal apps. Please suggest me the right type to choose for this.

At first I was thinking to use Portable class library supporting these 2 platforms but later on some researching found out Windows Runtime component(Universal apps) and read that using this would support app build using non managed code too(C++, JavaScript) which kind of seemed good for me. but when I try to refer this into a windows 8.1 app it says not supported, Do I need to build a separate windows runtime component again for this(I see Windows runtime component(portable for universal windows 8.1 template)?

Is there any chance I could build this without the need of having 2 projects for different platforms?

Comment: There's no silver bullet. To support platforms that far from each other, you will end up with multiple projects. But you can probably share a lot of code using linked files.

Answer (score 0):

I've been able to successfully use a WinRT component targeting Windows 8.1 in a Windows 10 app before, but it might have changed and YMMV. Try it out.